# How to repeat spinner dynamically?

Tags: android

I have `RelativeLayout` with `ScrollView` as the root element. In `RecyclerView` I have `spinner` and `TextView`. Now I am getting data from `JSON` like `RollNumber` and `Marks`. Now in `TextView`, I need to show `RollNumber` and in `Spinner` `Marks` should be displayed. I already got the data in `ArrayList<Progress>` and what should be the code will look like for this situation;

1. Do I have to repeat the `RelativeLayout` in for loop?

`OnCreate`

`for (int i = 0; i < progress.size(); i++) {`

```
progress_addmore_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  }
});
}
loadspinner
}
```

---

```
private void loadSpinners()
{
    if (progress != null || progress.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> progresscard = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < progress.size(); i++) {
            progresscard.add(progress.get(i).toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                progresscard);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        progress_addmore_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        if (progress.get(0).getMarks() != null && !progress.get(0).getMarks().isEmpty()) {
            product_addmore_spinner.setSelection(progresscard.indexOf(toppingtypelist.get(0).getMarks()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show what have you done please.put your code in question.

Comment: @NimaDerakhshanjan Please Verify the code

Comment: That's great,now your question has great readability.

Comment: @NimaDerakhshanjan Now I am trying to inflate the view, do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spinner including the adapter, the default value in the onBindViewHolder of the recyclerview adapter. Also set the position as the tag of the spinner in the adapter like: `vh.view.setTag(position);`

Now implement the OnItemSelectedListener in the activity or the fragment and pass it onto the recyclerview adapter. Since you have already set the position of the spinner as the tag, you can easily extract the index of the progress object in the ArrayList.

```
new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int index = (int) parent.getTag();

            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: @Rishabn Jain Sorry my mistake it's not `RecyclerView` it is `RelativeLayout`